# Is derived template class and base class layout compatible?

Tags: c++, inheritance, standards

I have two classes:

```
struct Base
{
    int a;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base
{};
```

Are they layout compatible or not?

**C++11 standard says ([class.mem]/16):**

Two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types are layout-compatible if they have the same number of non-static
data members and corresponding non-static data members (in declaration order) have layout-compatible types.

**But it also says ([class.derived]/8):**

A base class subobject might have a layout (3.7) different from the layout of a most derived object of the same type.

And it confused me.

**Note:**

This check

```
static_assert(__is_layout_compatible(Base, Derived<int>), "");
```

passed on GodBolt (compiler - x86-64 gcc(trunk)).

Comment: AFAIK the second note is not applicable to standard layout classes.

Comment: This is fairly simple: if you derive from `Base` and add all sort of things like virtual functions: your base class is still standard layout. Your derived class is not. That's all that this says.

Comment: Possibly relevant:  [std::is_layout_compatible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_layout_compatible) and [standard layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout).